# SQL - IF statement within a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm looking to add an IF statement into the below code that will  check if "Medicaid # from Prestige is ANYWHERE in the "[Medicaid # from Prestige]" cell.

If it is found, I want to have it display "TRUE" and if not then "FALSE" and am unsure how to do this within the code itself. I'm sure I am overlooking something, but have looked into the code, and haven't been able to find an exact way to pull this given my code needs.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
         pml.NPI AS [PML NPI] -- COALESCE will get first non null value
    ,pml.[Provider Name] as [Prov. Name from PML]
    ,pp.npi as [Prestige NPI]
    ,pp.last_name as [Last name (Prestige)]
    ,pp.first_name as [First name (Prestige)]
    ,case
        when pp.provider_type = 'i' then 'Individual'
      when pp.provider_type = 'g' then 'Group'
        else 'UNDEFINED'
    end as [Provider type]
    ,pp.Group_name as [Group name (Prestige)]
    ,case
        when pml.[Current Medicaid Enrollment Status A Active I Inactive E Ineligible] = 'A' then 'Active'
         when pml.[Current Medicaid Enrollment Status A Active I Inactive E Ineligible] = 'I' then 'Inactive'
      when pml.[Current Medicaid Enrollment Status A Active I Inactive E Ineligible] = 'E' then 'Ineligible'
        else 'UNDEFINED'
    end as [Medicaid Status]
    ,pml.[Florida Medicaid Provider ID] as [Medicaid # from PML]
    ,pp.medicaid_number as [Medicaid # from Prestige]
    ,case 
      when pml.[Florida Medicaid Provider ID]  like '*'+pp.medicaid_number+'*' then 'TRUE'
      else 'FALSE'
    end as [Medicaid match?]

    FROM [DWH].[dbo].[PML] as pml -- Full join shows all records, null will show for missing records
        FULL JOIN [DWH].[dbo].[PrestigeProviders] as pp  on pml.NPI = pp.npi
    WHERE (pml.npi IS not NULL AND pp.npi IS not NULL) -- only show when one side of the join fails
```

Adjusted my code, and get the following table (Truncated for relevant data and to prevent HIPAA violations):

```
Medicaid # from PML   Medicaid # from Prestige   Medicaid match?
18739600              018739600                  FALSE
13104200              013104200                  FALSE
9851900               009851900                  FALSE
10331600              009851900                  FALSE
```

Comment: Is this SQL Server? It's important to tag with the right dialect.

Comment: `CASE WHEN THEN ELSE`

Comment: modify the query in order to export a new field that implements CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END

Comment: you also tagged ssis which uses the C# method of.....  test? true part : false part

Comment: Updated the original post.

Comment: like '*' +pp.medicaid_number + '*'   not sure why it isn't display but add single quote star single quote around both sides.

Comment: Are the two things you are comparing always numeric? If so, instead of using the `LIKE` condition (which you are using improperly here since you didn't add any wildcards) you could compare the numeric values `case when CAST(pml.[Florida Medicaid Provider ID] as int) = CAST(pp.medicaid_number as int) THEN...`

Comment: Getting Medicaid # from PML Medicaid # from Prestige Medicaid match?
18739600 018739600 FALSE
13104200 013104200 FALSE
9851900 009851900 FALSE
10331600 009851900 FALSE

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: It's truncated because of the length of the SQL.

Comment: Full SQL statement in post.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause renders the `FULL OUTER JOIN` an `INNER JOIN`. And it seems you are only interested in matches anyway, as you want to compare the medicaid numbers from the tables. So why the obfuscation?

Comment: I am sure now you are using SQL Server and tagged your request accordingly. You can run `select @@version` in order to know which version you are using. Next time you ask a SQL question, please tag SQL Server and the version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The wildcard for `LIKE` is `%`, not `*`.
2. The concatenation symbol in standard SQL is `||` not `+`. But it's `+` in SQL Server.
3. It should be '009851900' like '%9851900%', not '9851900' like '%009851900%'.

Hence:

```
case when pp.medicaid_number like '%' + pml.[Florida Medicaid Provider ID] + '%' 
  then 'TRUE'
  else 'FALSE'
end as [Medicaid match?]
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near '|'.

Comment: @dragos_kai Thorsten was very clear :" in standard SQL".  You haven't told us what type of SQL you are using, this syntax varies.

Comment: You are using a DBMS that is not standard-compliant, as can be seen from the non-standard brackets for names. You have been asked twice which DBMS you are using. Which is it? I thought it might be SQL Server, but SQL Server would know `||` to be the concatenating operator. Obviously your DBMS does not only violate the standard in regards of brackets.

Comment: It's just standard SQL, SSMS and all that.

Comment: No this is definitely *not* standard SQL. But I looked it up; it does seem to be SQL Server you are using with SSMS. SQL Server needs `+` or `CONCAT` instead of the standard `||`. I didn't know that. (And unbelievable that they still don't support it - here is a feature request to Microsoft from 2007: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/259291/support-iso-9075-standard-string-concatenation-double-pipe). So use `+` or `CONCAT` then.

Comment: Changed it to   ,case when pml.[Florida Medicaid Provider ID] like CONCAT('%',pp.medicaid_number,'%')   
   then 'TRUE'
   else 'FALSE'
  end as [Medicaid match?] and I am still getting everything as FALSE

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that, it's `'009851900'` matching `'%9851900%'` of course, not vice versa. Hence: `pp.medicaid_number like CONCAT('%', pml.[Florida Medicaid Provider ID], '%')`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Oddly enough, now I'm getting Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Comment: The query itself works fine with varchar columns, as seen here: http://rextester.com/VGNUQ56490. So check your data types. Is `[Florida Medicaid Provider ID]` a`bigint` column? Then you'd have to cast (`pp.medicaid_number like '%' + cast(pml.[Florida Medicaid Provider ID] as varchar(max)) + '%' `).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the final line looked like   ,case when pp.medicaid_number like concat('%',cast(pml.[Florida Medicaid Provider ID] as varchar(max)),'%')
   then 'TRUE'
   else 'FALSE'
  end as [Medicaid match?]